# Passing Service Account Credential(JSON File) programmatically for BigQuery Service

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am exporting data from `BigQuery` table into `Google Cloud Storage` and I am able to do this successfully by using **Application Default Credentials**. I have set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in `bash_profile`(This environment variable points to my Service account `JSON` file) and this is how I am able to retrieve `BigQuery Service`(I am using `Scala`(Java API is used)).

```
val bigquery: BigQuery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
```

Now, I am trying to find a way to retrieve the `BigQuery` service by passing the service account `JSON` file programmatically instead of using the environment variable(i.e. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`)

```
val inputStream = this.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/GCCredentials.json")
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream)
val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService
```

But this code do not work and I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
```

What am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** - You're missing `FileInputStream`.

### Longer Version

Try this:

```
val fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/GCCredentials.json")
var credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(fileInputStream)
val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService()
```

Use `FileInputStream` to read the contents of your service account json file and pass the `FileInputStream` object to `GoogleCredentials` to build the credentials.

Alternatively (just for added information), you can use `ServiceAccountCredentials` instead of `GoogleCredentials` if you know that the format of the json file is in the service account credentials format.

[`GoogleCredentials`](http://google.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.7.1/apidocs/com/google/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredentials.html) is a base class to read OAuth2 credentials for use with any Google APIs, whereas [`ServiceAccountCredentials`](http://google.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.7.1/apidocs/com/google/auth/oauth2/ServiceAccountCredentials.html) is specific to service accounts. Using either of them will work with your case.

### Specifying project to use

You will most likely have to specify the project ID to use (if your environment does not provide this information). The library will attempt to guess the project ID to use if you do not set one explicitly.

You can specify the project ID using one of these environment variables:

- `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`
- `GCLOUD_PROJECT`

If these are not specified, it looks at your currently active `gcloud` configuration to detect the project to use.

You can also set this in code explicitly (like you described in your comments) as follows:

```
val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId("MY_PROJECT_ID").build().getService()
```

Comment: Looks like the code initially worked because it is taking the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Now I am getting this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A project ID is required for this service but could not be determined from the builder or the environment.  Please set a project ID using the builder.`... Although the file has project id

Comment: Looks like I have to specify the project ID by calling `BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).setProjectId(projectID).build().getService()`. The code works now. But would have been better if the project ID has been read by the API out of box

Comment: @Raj - Does your service account json file contain the `project_id` field?

Comment: it does have the field `project_id`

Comment: @Raj - You might want to confirm you have the latest version of the `google-cloud` java library. I verified that I can build the `BigQuery` object without setting a project ID and still invoke all operations like `listDatasets()` for example. Since the service account is tied to a specified project, it should be able to figure out the associated project without having to specify it explicitly. BTW, I tried this using java - but I don't think scala should be any different here since they both run on JVM. The exact version I used is `com.google.cloud:google-cloud:0.20.3-alpha`

Comment: @Raj - Just realized that it picks up a default project based on your currently active local `gcloud` configuration if it exists, if you do not specify one in `BigQueryOptions.Builder`. If no `projectId` has been specified and one does not exist in your current environment, I see the same error you mentioned. Alternatively the project can be specified instead using `GCLOUD_PROJECT` environment variable.